# Android instrumented unit test will not run on one physical device

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, androidx

I have one device that throws an exception when I try to run unit tests on a project recently converted to use the androidX support libraries.  The tests have run on emulators and other physical devices.

The device it will not run on is a Pixel 2 running 9.

App crashes with this exception:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime: PID: 7050
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call to getContentProviderExternal for: android_support_test_services.speak_easy returns null!
AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection$ToolConnectionPostIcs.doCall(ToolConnection.java:155)
AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:93)
AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.test.services.speakeasy.client.ToolConnection.publish(ToolConnection.java:83)
AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.BlockingPublish.getResult(BlockingPublish.java:79)
AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellCommandExecutorServer.start(ShellCommandExecutorServer.java:80)
AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain.main(ShellMain.java:45)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:340)
AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad file descriptor
AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1127)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.handleApplicationCrash(IActivityManager.java:3711)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:143)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1955)
```

Simplified Unit Test:

```
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test

class MyTest {

    @Rule
    var activityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<AuthAppActivity> = object : ActivityTestRule<AuthAppActivity>(AuthAppActivity::class.java, false, false) {
        override fun afterActivityLaunched() {
        }

        override fun beforeActivityLaunched() {
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun runTest() {

        Assert.assertTrue(true);   // low standards here
    }
}
```

And the relevant dependencies:

```
testImplementation('junit:junit:4.12') {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'

androidTestImplementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0"

androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.1.0"

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'

androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0"
```

Comment: Same here. I opened a bug report on AndroidX Test: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/397

Answer (score 1):

The provider android_support_test_services.speak_easy is obviously missing from the device.  I ran the test on the working device and see that the same provider is used and found on that device.  I pulled up an older branch, prior to AndroidX, ran the a instrumented test from there and then switched back, the error was gone.

Older version installed these versions:

```
test-services-1.0.2.apk
orchestrator-1.0.2.apk
```

Newer androidx:

```
orchestrator-1.1.0-alpha3.apk
test-services-1.1.0-alpha3.apk
```

Comment: I would also try to switch away from activityTestRule and try to use ActivityScenario

Comment: @MarkHan, I'm not familiar with an ActivityScenario and my searches have been futile, can you share a link to the docs?

Comment: It is a new API released with AndroidX Test that is a replacement of ActivityController in Robolectric and ActivityTestRule in the support library. ActivityScenario provides APIs to start and drive an Activity's lifecycle state for testing. Check out "Testing Rebooted" video from the Android Dev Summit 2018 https://youtu.be/4m2yYSTdvIg?t=378 
Also:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/write-once-run-everywhere-tests-on-android-88adb2ba20c5

From Early November 2018

Comment: Official ActivityScenario Documenation: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks @MarkHan

Comment: FWIW I'm seeing the same errors even on instrumentation tests that don't interact/drive/test Activities.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this after realizing I was using an old version of Test Orchestrator [link](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/397#issuecomment-516158786) I was accidentally depending on the old `android.support.test` version, not the `androidx.test` version, even though I'd updated all the other test packages to androidx.test.